# Conditionally rendering component sections in React JSX

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator, reactjs

According to [MDN](http://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/conditional_operator) "You can also do more than one single operation per case, separating them with a comma." The example below works:

```
var stop = false, age = 23;

age > 18 ? (
    alert("1"),
    alert("2")
) : (
    stop = true,
    alert("Sorry, you are much too young!")
);
```

But I can't seem to do the same in React as seen below. I expect both "Yes" and "No" buttons to be displayed, but it as it only displays the "No" button.

```
return (
  <div className="topcoat-list">
    <ul className="topcoat-list__container">
    {
      notes.map(function (note) {
        var title = note.content.substring(0, note.content.indexOf("\n"));
title = title || note.content;
        var toggleDeleteDialogs = this.state.isConfirming && note.id === notepad.selectedId;
        var disableDelete = this.state.isConfirming && note.id !== notepad.selectedId;

          return (
          <li key={note.id} onClick={this.onSelectNote.bind(null, note.id)} className="topcoat-list__item">
            {title}

            {
              toggleDeleteDialogs ?
              (
                <button key={note.id} onClick={this.deleteThisNote.bind(null, note.id)} className="half">Yes</button>,
                <button className="half" onClick={this.onCancelDelete}>No</button>
              ) : (
              <button key={note.id} onClick={this.deleteThisNote.bind(null, note.id)} className="full" disabled={disableDelete ? "disabled" : ""}>Delete Note</button>
              )
            }

          </li>

        );
      }.bind(this))
    }
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Full markup: https://jsfiddle.net/55fvpcLo/

Is my syntax off or could this be done more elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle doesn't seem to be working, but I can reproduce the behavior. Although it doesn't raise the `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag` error, I suspect that that may be the reason it doesn't work, since adjacent elements is effectively what you're trying to do.

I think the simplest solution is just to wrap the two elements in an enclosing tag rather than parentheses.

Comment: That worked thanks. I have bumped into that issue before, but that didn't cross my mind this time. Like you said, no error generated.

Answer (score 2):

You could also return an array of JSX-components, e.g.

```
{ 
  toggleDeleteDialogs ?
  [<Button ... />, <Button ... />] :
  <Button .../> 
}
```

Comment: Great, I quite like that this option prevents [divitis](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=div-itis). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Adam Stone is right that the problem is that there are adjacent JSX elements not wrapped in a closing tag.

That said, you asked for the most elegant way to solve the problem.

I made the following changes to your code:

- Used this function to selectively hide JSX elements:

  ```
  var hideIfFalse=function(boolean){
        return boolean? {} : {display : 'none'};
   };
  ```

  which you can use like this:

  ```
  <div style={hideIfFalse(toggleDeleteDialogs)} />
  ```
- Separated the logic for rendering the list items into a `renderChildren` method:

  ```
  renderChildren:function(notes,classes){
    return  notes.map(function (note) {
    //...
  ```
- Made a `DeleteDialog` component. It has reusable functionality with its own rendering logic, and separating it out improves code readability:

  ```
  var DeleteDialog=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
      var classes=this.props.classes;

      return <div style={hideIfFalse(this.props.toggleDeleteDialogs)}>
            <button onClick={this.props.onDelete} className="half">
              Yes
            </button>,
            <button className="half" onClick={this.props.onCancelDelete}>
              No
            </button>
      </div>
    }
  });
  ```
- I didn't touch the `classSet` logic but don't understand what it's supposed to do.

[Putting it all together](http://jsfiddle.net/55fvpcLo/2/):

```
   var hideIfFalse=function(boolean){
        return boolean? {} : {display : 'none'};
    };

    var notepad = {
      notes:
      [
          {
              id: 1,
              content: "Hello, world!\nBoring.\nBoring.\nBoring."
          },
          {
              id: 2,
              content: "React is awesome.\nSeriously, it's the greatest."
          },
          {
              id: 3,
              content: "Robots are pretty cool.\nRobots are awesome, until they take over."
          },
          {
              id: 4,
              content: "Monkeys.\nWho doesn't love monkeys?"
          }
      ],
      selectedId: 1
    };

    var DeleteDialog=React.createClass({
      render:function(){
        var classes=this.props.classes;

        return <div style={hideIfFalse(this.props.toggleDeleteDialogs)}>
              <button onClick={this.props.onDelete} className="half">
                Yes
              </button>,
              <button className="half" onClick={this.props.onCancelDelete}>
                No
              </button>
        </div>
      }

    })

    var NotesList = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          isConfirming: false
        };
      },

      onSelectNote: function(id) {
          notepad.selectedId = id;
      },

      deleteThisNote: function(noteId) {
        if(this.state.isConfirming) {
          // actual delete functionality should be here
          this.setState({isConfirming: false});
        }
        else {
          this.setState({isConfirming: true});
        }
      },

      onCancelDelete: function() {
        this.setState({ isConfirming: false });
      },
      renderChildren:function(notes,classes){
        return  notes.map(function (note) {
                var title = note.content.substring(0, note.content.indexOf("\n"));
                title = title || note.content;
                var toggleDeleteDialogs = this.state.isConfirming && note.id === notepad.selectedId;
                var disableDelete = this.state.isConfirming && note.id !== notepad.selectedId;
                  return <li key={note.id}
                          onClick={this.onSelectNote.bind(null, note.id)} 
                          className="topcoat-list__item">
                          {title}
                            <button key={note.id} onClick={this.deleteThisNote.bind(null, note.id)} className="full" disabled={disableDelete ? "disabled" : ""}>Delete Note</button>
                            <DeleteDialog
                            toggleDeleteDialogs={toggleDeleteDialogs}
                            note={note}
                            onDelete={this.deleteThisNote.bind(null, note.id)}
                            onCancelDelete={this.onCancelDelete.bind(this)} />
                         </li>
                }.bind(this))
      },

      render: function() {
        var notes = notepad.notes;
        var cx = React.addons.classSet;
        var classes = cx({
          "topcoat-button-bar__button": true,
          "full": !this.state.isConfirming,
          "half": this.state.isConfirming,
        });

        return (
          <div className="topcoat-list">
            <ul className="topcoat-list__container">
              {this.renderChildren(notes,classes)}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    React.render(<NotesList />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55fvpcLo/2/

Comment: Thanks for the great ideas for composing.